# IF checkbox is checked ONLOAD, display textbox, IF NOT, do not show textbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

Is there a way in javascript that i can already show a textbox if checkbox is checked Onload? then hide the textbox if it is not checked onload?

Comment: Good news: Yes you can!

Comment: Hi @RokoC.Buljan, i tried doing this,
 ` $('.checkbox_pram_model').click(function() {
           if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
              $(".select_pram_model").show();
           } else {
              $("select_pram_model").hide();
           }
          }); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```js
var checkbox = document.getElementById('check');

if (checkbox.checked == true) {
  //do nothing
} else {
  checkbox.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check" checked>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple stuff, using eventlistener.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').forEach(chk => {
    document.querySelectorAll(`input[type="text"].${chk.className}`).forEach(i => i.classList.add('hide'));
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="test1" checked>
<input type="text" class="test1">
<input type="checkbox" class="test2">
<input type="text" class="test2">
```